# Check-in previous version of file

Tags: tfs

I had to rollback a few files for a period of time and now I would like to 'reinstate' one these files.

I am doing this:

1. Check out the file in question
2. Get specific version (using the changeset number of the file version
   I want to reinstate). Both check boxes to overwrite are checked. This presents the merge conflict dialog.
3. Whether I merge or take server version it brings down the correct
   version but undoes the checkout (from #1 above)
4. Checking out the file again reverts to the most recent version

What is the best way to get the older version of the file checked in (other than select all from the previous version, check out and then do a paste?

Note: "Get latest version of item on check out" in VS options.

Answer (score 0):

1. clear the file in question from your local workspace
2. Get specific version (i.e. the previously rolled back version) Tick the 2 force boxes
3. Check in the file

usualy works for me