# TFS check out specific version, make changes, check in

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, tfvc

Can this be done in Visual Studio Team Services and Visual Studio Professional 2015?

Looking at [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f436a587-bcd5-4911-b8c9-195181f6a82d/unable-to-checkout-a-specific-version-from-tfs-2010?forum=tfsbuild) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26345752/check-in-previous-version-of-file) it seems not...

But if you check out a file [you automatically get latest version] I've noticed that you can get a specific version from here, what I haven't tested is if you can make changes to this specific version before checking back in.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do the following:

1) Go to ***Tools-->Options***, select ***Source Control-->Visual Studio Team Foundation Server***.  Un-check 2 options shown below.
[image]

2) For the file you'd like to edit, select the file, right click and **View History**.  In the history screen, select the version you would like to edit. Right click and select ***Get This Version***.

[image]

3) In Solution Explorer, double click the file and it should open the version you selected in the History view.

[image]

4) Make your edits and ***Check-In***.  You will get a **Resolve Conflicts** screen.  From there either **Merge Changes In Merge Tool** or select **Keep Local Version** to check in the file as is.

[image]

Comment: After doing this, I got a warning "All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server.
"